# angular - $index not repeated correctly in some form input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem when i want to repeat `$index` in some form input

i can provide it in my fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/fyanz92/tK3Ce/

this is my controller:

```
var pesan = angular.module("pesan", []);

pesan.controller("datapesan", function ($scope) {
    $scope.penumpanglain = {
        data: [{
            nama_penumpang: '',
            no_hp: null,
            alamat_penjemputan: '',
            alamat_tujuan: ''
        }]
    };

    $scope.addPenumpang = function () {
        $scope.penumpanglain.data.push({
            nama_penumpang: '',
            no_hp: null,
            alamat_penjemputan: '',
            alamat_tujuan: ''
        });
    };

    $scope.removePenumpang = function (index) {
        $scope.penumpanglain.data.splice(index, 1);
    };


});
```

if you watch the output in my fiddles then you click 'Add Penumpang' button, `$index` not repeated correctly with pattern : `2,2,2,2` then `3,2,2,2, etc.. n` how to correct it?

Comment: You have a typo at some places in HTML: Change `index` to `$index`

Comment: oh, thanks for help.. i'm not thoroughly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$index` only for the first input others are `index` see http://jsfiddle.net/tK3Ce/7/